# get type IRepo<T> when i have the string name for T

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

basically

I have

```
string s = "Foo"
```

I need to obtain

```
 Type t = IRepo<Foo>
```

but from string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this, using [`Type.MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx):

```
Type arg = Type.GetType(s);
Type definition = typeof(IRepo<>);
Type concrete = definition.MakeGenericType(arg);
```

Note that [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) comes with a few caveats:

- You need to specify the type's full name, including namespace
- If you want to get a type from an assembly other than `mscorlib` or the calling assembly, you have to include the assembly name
- If you're including the assembly name and it's strongly typed, you need the full assembly name including version etc.

Comment: A few more points:
If you know which assembly the type exists in, you can use Assembly.GetType, which should be able to resolve a fully qualified type-name without assembly information being attached to the type-string.

If all you have is "Foo", then AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany (a => a.GetTypes()).Single(t => t.Name == "Foo") or similar may be your only choice, but this is brittle and risky.

Answer (score 4):

```
Type t = typeof (IRepo<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var someTypeName = "Foo";
var someType = Type.GetType("Namespace.To." + someTypeName);
typeof(IRepo<>).MakeGenericType(someType);
```

You first need to get the `Type` of `Foo`, and then you can pass that into Type.MakeGenericType.